# In the second round of Invasion: Spire, where does the shotgun spawn?

Tags: halo-reach

In the second round of Invasion: Spire, when the Spartans are trying to capture the points at the bottom of the spire, I have seen people using the shotgun, but none of the loadouts have it so it must spawn on the map. Does anyone know where the shotgun spawn is for this round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're coming from the Spartan spawn, the shotgun is on the far right side, leaned up against a metal fence.  There's also a rocket launcher, nearest the left spawn, and a sniper rifle up against the rocks near the middle spawn.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the rocket and sniper spawns, but I never noticed the shotgun.

Comment: Having these weapons really makes a difference for sure.  I also like to grab the Fuel Rod gun in the third phase, which is near the Covenant manpult, I think over near where the Banshee spawns.